# How to skip removed ref while using populate() in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

There is a `MyCollection` schema with:

```
...
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true, // the same with false
    ref: 'Author'
},
...
```

And the code:

```
MyCollection
    .find(filter, '_id author text')
    .populate('author', '_id name')
    .exec(),
```

If the document with `author` was removed from `Authors` collection, the populate method above throws the following error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')

The question is: How can populate() be configured **to ignore removed ref's** and simply return the document without the `author` field?

Comment: hmm is the error coming from the query?

Comment: or are you later trying to access a null field?

Comment: @cmgchess, just calling query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ignoring removed refs is a good idea. It would be better to remove the ref if the subdocument `author` has been deleted. The Mongoose default behaviour is to return [null](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#doc-not-found) when there's no document, hence the error message you received. Mongoose provides you with two helper methods to check if the field is populated. You could try to incorporate:

```
// Returns a truthy value if author populated   
MyCollection.populated('author'); 


// Make author not populated anymore
MyCollection.depopulate('author');
```

However, I would suggest you refactor your code so that when a document from author collection is deleted you pass the `author._id` of the deleted document so that it can be pulled from the `MyCollection`. Something like:

```
const deletedAuthor = await authorModel.findByIdAndDelete(authorid);
const myCollection = await myCollectionModel.findById(parentId);
myCollection.author.pull(authorid);
await myCollection.save();
```

Also, you don't need to include `_id` in your `.populate('author', '_id name')` projection because according to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only) the `_id` field is returned as default on matching documents.

You can remove null fields after your query using basic JavaScript but you need to change `exec()` to the `lean()` method so that POJO are returned like so:

```
const myCollection = await MyCollection
.find(filter, '_id author text')
.populate('author', '_id name')
.lean();

const myCollectionFiltered = myCollection.map((doc)=>{
   if(doc.author === null){
      delete doc.author;
   }
   return doc;
});
```

Now `myCollectionFiltered` contains no null values for author.

Comment: Thank you. So you say, like no easy option to ignore removed ref? Because, all that options above looks weird and updating myCollection is also not an option in my case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem lies somewhere else in your code. The error message you posted `Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')` is thrown when you try to access a property of null so your query would't throw it. Are you trying to access `author._id` in your controller or view perhaps? I have replicated your models and your query does not thrown an error.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to remove null course values after your query returns. The [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) pipeline can do similar and is very powerful.

Comment: Thank you. I found that you're right. There is a place later where author._id is called, and I accidentally skipped it while reviewing. Big thanks again for pointing that out.